# .htaccess subdomain url rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite an url, but I always do not get any adequate results.

I would like the url 
http://something.domain.com/index.php?arguments... 
to actually visit
http://domain.com/index.php?username=something&arguments...

I have tried with making a wildcard entry *.domain.com and using some code on the internet, but nothing worked.

I keep getting a "Default Website Page"
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `something` domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ http://%2/$1?username=%1 [L,QSA,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "something" is actually the username.
So, martin.domain.com should be equivalent to domain.com/index.php?username=martin

Comment: It still shows me the "Default webpage" message. Should I delete the dns entry "*.domain.com"?

Comment: What URL do you see in your browser?

Comment: This is the sample url: http://martin.paneluser.com/
I want it to actually access paneluser.com?index.php?username=martin

Comment: Yes as per this rule it should show `http://paneluser.com?index.php?username=martin` is URL not changing at all in browser?

Comment: The problem is that it shows the default webpage and I do not know why. It doesn't show the contents of index.php

Comment: That is what I was asking: **what is URL for the default webpage you see in your browser**?

Comment: I cannot find it. It is on a reseller hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help!
It seems that I do not have to add a wildcard dns entry, but to create a wildcard sub-domain in cpanel.